# which command is fast to search consecutive patterns in a line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

which command is fast to search consecutive patterns in a line in unix ?
The word "=" follows the word "Model".

Input File

```
Model = It supports 10 Modular Controllers
Support Config Page Model = Yes
Model files are here
```

Output:

```
Extract the line where word "=" comes after the word "Model" and "Model" appears as a first word. 
Here first line of input file satisfy the criteria- "Model = It supports 10 Modular Controllers"
```

I have used sed and awk commands but want to know which one is better.

```
sed -n '/^Model/ s/=/&/p'
sed -n 's/^Model.*=/&/p'
sed -n '/^Model/ {/=/p ;}'

awk '/^Model.*=/'
```

Can someone please tell me which one is fast and better.

Comment: when you said `Extract the line which have words "Model" and "="`, I understand 1) `Model` and `=` could be anywhere in a line, 2) the order of the two key words is not checked. so none of your example work.  If you ask a question, try making the requirement clear

Comment: `grep` seems to be the tool you need for this task.

Comment: You may try similar sed command `sed -n 's/Model = .* \([0-9][0-9]*\) .*/Found: \1/p' file`, Output: `Found: 10`

Comment: `awk '$1$2 == "Model="'` should do it without regexes, which will be significantly faster, but I'm unsure about your desired output format.  I gave you something that merely prints that line without modification.

Comment: `man time` and try them.

Answer (score 0):

As Ed Morton says, without RegEx is faster. My proposed solution is

```
awk '{a=index($0, "Model");b=index($0, "=")}a==1 && a<b'
```

First I get the position for the substrings, and then I compare them to avoid a double search for Model, Another solution could be:

```
awk 'index($0, "Model")!=1{next}index($0, "=")>1'
```

In both scripts I'm assuming that Model must be the first word (you are using the "^" in your regexps) And in this second script I check that Model is present and is the first word in string, once this is validated I only check that the "=" comes after the "Model" (its position its greater than 1)

Comment: I didn't say that, @AdamKatz did (and he's right). That's the 2nd time today someones attributed someone else's comment to me (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38508525/1745001) and AFAIK it's maybe only happened once or twice in the 5 years or so before. Weird... Anyway - using 2 function calls plus math will be slower than using one function call (match($0,regexp)) or none (/regexp/) so that may negate any benefit to a string vs regexp match.